# visiting first level of directory and get Size of each directory Java

Tags: java, java-8

I need the list of the directories in the C: And get size for each one.
I am trying with this  code:

```
int[] count = {0};
try {
    Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(dir.getPath()), new HashSet<FileVisitOption>(Arrays.asList(FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)),
            Integer.MAX_VALUE, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file , BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    System.out.printf("Visiting file %s\n", file);
                    ++count[0];

                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file , IOException e) throws IOException {
                    System.err.printf("Visiting failed for %s\n", file);

                    return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
                }

                @Override
                public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir , BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                     System.out.printf("About to visit directory %s\n", dir);
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem I have is that if I use exactly this, Takes a lot of time because it visits each file! of the disk.  I tried with differents options for FileVisitResult but I can't get the desired result.  I need only first level with space in the disk. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Note that logging during the file visiting may sinificantly slow down the operation, as every log message has a cost. You could try logging every 1000 files to see if it goes faster

Comment: "Takes a lot of time because it visits each file" - in order to calculate the memory consumption you'd need to visit each file. If you do something like `du --max-depth=1` on a linux system that still will visit each file - it just will only report the size for one level. However, the main problem with your code is most likely what Fernando pointed out: logging slows it down a lot.

Comment: Is it actually possible to make it really fast? If you want to check size of directory directly from windows explorer it might take couple seconds as well if there are many files. Don't know about linux system tho.

Comment: This also depends on your disk. If you have a 5400RPM HDD, compared to a samsung evo 970 plus SSD, the difference is going to be tremendous :)

Comment: Do you want size of data in the files or size on disk? Windows typically uses 4,096 byte blocks. Plus for small files the data is stored in the MFT.

Comment: You shouldn't FOLLOW_LINKS when calculating folder sizes.

Answer (score 4):

Folders do not have a (significant) size of their own. Usually when a folder size is discussed, the meaning is **the sum of sizes of all files under that folder and its sub-folders**. This operation takes a "very long" time for C:\ (try right-clicking your Program Files folder and hitting properties). Remove all logs and try again. Compare the time it took your code, with the time it takes Windows Explorer to calculate that size (again, by right-clicking your Program Files folder and hitting properties).

In any case, Apache's `commons-io` has a one-liner:

```
long size = FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(folder);
```

And Java-8 has another "pure" one-liner:

```
long size = Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\"))
      .filter(p -> p.toFile().isFile())
      .mapToLong(p -> p.toFile().length())
      .sum();
```

Comment: `Files.walk` will fail if inside the folder there is a folder which the program has no permission . With `walkFileTree` you avoid that ... though  more lines . Learned it the hard way :)